# Bulk Insert problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I have a stored procedure that makes bulk insert from some file:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_BulkInsert] @FileName NVARCHAR(200) AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @bulkinsert NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @bulkinsert = N'BULK INSERT TblTemp FROM ''' + @FileName + 
       N''' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')'

EXEC sp_executesql @bulkinsert

RETURN @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

This stored procedure runs fine when I run it from SQL Server Management Studio, but when I try to run it with `ExecuteNonQuery` of ADO.NET I get the following error:

> "The INSERT permission was denied on the object 'TblTemp', database
>   'TempDB', schema 'dbo'."

Important: all other stored procedures (that make `SELECT/INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE`) run fine from ADO.NET.

The user under which all the things are run is a member of the `bulkadmin` role, and also a member of a custom `db_executer` role (that has just EXECUTE permission).

The code runs fine for a lot of stored procedures, it's a first time that it fails..
This is the function

```
public static int BulkInsert(string fileName)
{
    SqlParameter paramFileName = new SqlParameter("FileName", fileName);
    SqlParameter paramRetValue = new SqlParameter();
    paramRetValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
    SqlParameter[] @parameters = { paramFileName, paramRetValue };
    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(ConnectionSettings.ConnectionString,
    CommandType.StoredProcedure, "SP_BulkInsert", parameters, true);

    return (int)paramRetValue.Value;
}
```

I logging into the SSMS with the same username/password that are in the connection string on ADO.NET side..

The bottom question is, why in Management Studio the stored procedure succeed, while via ADO.NET it fails (with the above error message).

Comment: Can you show us the ADO.NET code you're using??

Comment: @marc_s. Mark, thank you for the edditing..

The code works fine for a lot of time with a lot of stored procedures..

ExecuteNonQuery(ConnectionSettings.ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "SP_SomeBulkInsert", parameters, true);

Comment: thanks - but could you please put this into your original question - not here in comments where's its awfully hard to read. Also: the important and interesting things would be the connection string, how you set up the connection etc - **not just** that one line!!

Comment: Are u sure u want to put this into TempDB?
maybe u want to put it into another database...try using 
`Use [insert_ur_Databasename_here]` before u do the bulk insert

Comment: @Mulki No.. There is a 'use TempDB' clause in the stored procedure.. There is on only database with these table and stored procedure..

Answer (score 1):

Running SQL via the sp_executesql uses different permissions than directly in the stored procedure.  I would advise checking that the user which you are running the stored procedure as has (in this instance) INSERT permissions against the table "TblTemp".

To do this in Sql Server Management Studio...

- expand the list of tables
- right click on the appropriate one and select properties
- on the "permissions" tab, click the "Add..." button.
- Either type in the user or role, or "Browse..." for it.
- with the user or role selected in the top table, tick "Grant" in the appropriate permissions in the "Explicit permissions for {username/role}"
- click OK

Comment: I run THE SAME stored procedure 'SP_BulkInsert'.. In Management Studio it succeed, via ADO.NET it fails.. Why?

Comment: Are you logging into SSMS with the same username/password as the one you're running the stored procedure with through ADO?  In my experience, a stored procedure with a normal TSQL statement in it will run correctly even if the user doesn't have direct SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE permissions on the table.  However, if that TSQL statement is run through the dynamic sp_executesql command, I do not believe it is using the same user, and therefore doesn't have the correct permissions on the table.

Comment: I logging into the SSMS with the same username/password that are in the connection string on ADO.NET side.. So under what user SQL server runs dynamic queries? How can I know its permissions?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the knowledge to answer that... but I would suggest trying to set the permissions directly on the table(s) in question for the connection string username, as that has always worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The Management Studio must be running on the sa account which has all privileges, but the user that you are connecting through ADO.NET may not have the correct privileges set. You need to give the users writing permissions through the Management studio. Look in the users list.

Comment: I logging into the SSMS with the same username/password that are in the connection string on ADO.NET side.. I added this point to the question, thanks..